# Como puedo sumar los elementos de 3 listas

Tags: python

como puedo hacer que el print me muestre solo 5 valores? (los resultados de las sumas de las listas)

```
num1 = [1,2,3,4,5]
num2 = [1,2,3,4,5]
num3 = [1,2,3,4,5]

for x in num1:
    for y in num2:
        for d in num3:
            print(x+y+d)
```

Comment: `sum(num1+num2+num3)`

Comment: `suma = [num1[i] + num2[i] + num3[i] for i in range(len(num1))]`

Comment: @CandidMoe, apenas vi que tu comentario era igual que una parte de mi respuesta. Te citaré.

Answer (score 3):

## Usando zip y map

Puedes utilizar `zip` junto con `map` y la función `sum`:

```
>>> sum1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> num2 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> num3 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]


>>> list(map(sum, zip(num1, num2, num3)))

>>> [3, 6, 9, 12, 15]
```

Lo que hace `zip` es que cada entrada de cada elemento la pone en el mismo lugar de la misma tupla. Por ejemplo:

```
l1 = (1,2)
l2 = (3,4)
list(zip(l1,l2))
```

Te regresa un: `[(1,3), (2,4)]`, es decir, como que agrupa los elementos de la misma entrada.

Y ya después, con la función `sum` en `map`, estos elementos del mismo número de entrada se suman.

## Sumando entrada por entrada

Otra opción que te han dado en los comentarios a tu publicación, y que creo que es más legible pero tediosa de escribir, es sumando entrada por entrada

```
>>> [num1[i] + num2[i] + num3[i] for i in range(len(num1))]
[3, 6, 9, 12, 15]
```

Answer (score 0):

for también.

```
lista1=[1,2,3,4,5]
lista2=[1,2,3,4,5]
lista3=[1,2,3,4,5]
suma=0
for i in range(len(lista1)): 

  suma+=lista1[i]+lista2[i]+lista3[i]
  print(suma,end=' ')
  suma=0
```

Comment: En la pregunta se muestran 3 listas y no una

Comment: @Christian. El código suma las tres listas. Sólo usa la primera para determinar en rango a iterar.

Comment: @CandidMoe eso es ahora, antes de la edición el código no hacía eso

Comment: Bueno como tienen el mismo números de elementos las tres listas, sólo me interesa que sume cada elemento de cada lista, por eso Itero con la primera lista, sólo por el número de sumas por elemento, y si, cierto antes de editar por segunda vez entendí mal el enunciado. Lo arreglé después. Un saludo

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar `zip` para unir las listas:

```py
all_num = zip(num1, num2, num3)
```

`zip` empareja los elementos de cada iterable (listas en este caso) que se le pasa como argumento. Todos los primeros, luego los segundos, etc. Pero como `zip`retorna un iterador sólo puedes verlo cuando lo recorres o lo conviertes en una lista (y solo la primera vez):

```py
print(list(all_num))
[(1, 1, 1), (2, 2, 2), (3, 3, 3), (4, 4, 4), (5, 5, 5)]
```

Sabiendo esto puedes recorrer la lista y sumar los valores de las tuplas:

```py
for tupla in zip(num1, num2, num3):
  print(sum(tupla))
```

Comment: se pide la suma de todas las listas para eso debes almacenar cada resultado de `sum(tupla)` y volver a sumar todo

Comment: @Cristian, entiendo que pide la suma de los elementos de cada lista con el mismo índice, ¿no?